# how to remotely run commands on a pc by using powershell

Tags: powershell

what I am trying to do is using powershell to execute this command "xxx.exe register -key:xxxxx" on a remote computer's cmd in a specific path. How can I do it? This is the command that I want to run on a remote computer.

```
Start-Process $xxxPath\xxx.exe -ArgumentList "register -key:$xxKey" -Wait -WindowStyle hidden
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -Wait -ArgumentList "Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {cmd /k xxx.exe register -key:xxxxx}" -Credential $cred

Comment: what does the variable k mean ? also why after the filepath is powershell  instead of the path of the exe file? Thanks